# How can i find a number after character in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I find a numeric number in the same cell after character. For ex After J* find number 01. I will have few rows and inside row some value will J*01 or J*08 im trying separate between character and number using instar in VBA:

```
Sub zz()

  Dim ii As Long, z As Integer, xlastrow As Long
  Dim yy As String
   xlastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
      For ii = 1 To xlastrow
        yy = "J*"
         z = 1
       If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & ii)) Then

  This line separating number after J* character and pasting it to sheet2
Seprate.Find.Range("B" & ii, yy).Value = Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("A" & z)
          End If
          z = z + 1
      Next ii

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an input value in the cell and the output you want e.g. `GfsfsssJ*07ndg` requires an output of `07`

Comment: See:  http://superuser.com/questions/892164/how-can-i-find-a-number-after-character-in-vba

Comment: @Alex P ya sure input value for ex should be like xx1J*112xx so i just want the digit after J* so output should be like this 112...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

' paste the values in column A.

```
  q1w2e3r4asJ*66bvft654
  1234BA
  BA1234BA
  xuz12354
```

''''' Code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Remove_Charecter()

Dim Last_Row As Double
Dim num As Double
Dim i  As Integer
Dim j  As Integer

Last_Row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Last_Row

    num = 0
    For j = 1 To Len(Cells(i, 1))

        If IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)) Then
            num = Trim(num & Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1))
        End If
    Next j
    Cells(i, 2).Value = (num)
Next i
    'MsgBox num

End Sub
```

'--- Output will be

```
123466654
1234
1234
12354
```

Comment: my input will be like this J*112 or ffxJ*2333 so i just want the number after J* (character).... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below piece of codes.

**Assumption**

1. Your data that you need to separate is in Column A
2. There is no blank cells in your data
3. Trim value will be displayed in the adjacent column i.e. Column B in subsequent cells

Code :

```
Dim LRow As Double
Dim i  As Integer
Dim j  As Integer
Dim LPosition As Integer
Dim Number As Double

LRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To LRow
    Number = 0
    LPosition = InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "J*")
    For j = (LPosition + 2) To Len(Cells(i, 1))

        If IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)) Then
            num = Trim(num & Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1))
        End If
        Next j
Cells(i, 2).Value = Number

Next i
```

Comment: what does LPosition + 2 mean ... and what is tha J loop doin

Comment: **Lposition** will give the number of position of J* and +2 means start the extraction of 2nd character and onwards after the first occurrence of J*. And the J loop is looping from Lposition+2 to rest of the length of string for the checking of numeric value and combine them. Is this solution working for you???

Comment: oh ok i c your point but hmm kinda not but i understood the logic another thing i want to ask you what if i have J*xx1223, J*xx333 and i wan it to have a output 12234 row1 and 333 row2 to column B or any other column

Comment: As it was given in sample code u have written that you want the number after J* so the programme was according to that scenario and the above code works perfactly for the sample **J*112 or ffxJ*2333** given by u. Now for the the second case u just need to replace J* with Jxx in coding and Lposition+2 with Lposition+3 and that will do the task :-)